# C File I/O Trouble

Tags: c, file, parsing, io

I am trying to make a method in C that can look at all the characters in a specified file, and count the # of appearances of a particular character.

So...

Input: Some_File.c

Output: The Letter "J" Occurred: 'x' times in your file.

What I have SO FAR:

```
int main()
{
    int jsCount = jsCounter();
    fin(jsCount);
}

//this counts # of "j"s in a file

int jsCounter()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    int count = 0;
    char myChar =   "j";
    fp = fopen("Doc.c", "r");

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if ( c == myChar)
            count = count + 1;
    }
    return count;
}

//This sends info to User (How many "j"s were found)

fin(int jsCount)
{
    printf("You have a total of");
    printf("%d" jsCount);
}
```

Errors I am getting:

The correct number is not being returned by the method... 
warnings that...
"initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|"

*edit*I am returning a value of 0 for the count, even if there are more than 0 j's in the document
I come from Java and am very new to C... any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is wrong

   ```
   char myChar =   "j";
   ```

   it's attempting to assign the address of the constant string `"j"` to `myChar`, the correct way is

   ```
   char myChar = 'j';
   ```

   In c, string literals are delimited by double quotes `"some string"` and character constants by single qoutes like `'x'`, the expression `'x'` gives the ascii code of the character `x`.

   There are multi-character character constants too, but they are implementation defined, so I couldn't tell you what they mean.

   Depending on what compiler you are using, you can enable compiler warnings, that will prevent this kind of mistake, for `gcc` you can use the following

   ```
   gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wextra -Werror ${source} -o ${program}
   ```

   **Note**: check that `fopen()` didn't return `NULL`, because if it did you should not try to read from the file.
2. You didn't include any header files you need

   - `stdio.h`
3. You need to declare the functions before using them in `main()`

   ```
   void fin(int jsCount);
   int jsCounter();
   ```
4. `fin()` needs a return type, if it's not meant to return anything then `void`

   ```
   void
   fin(int jsCount)
   {
       printf("You have a total of");
       printf("%d", jsCount);
   }
   ```
5. The last `printf()` in `fin()` lacks a `,` that is needed between the format string and the parameter, you could actually just

   ```
   printf("You have a total of %d\n", jsCount);
   ```
6. Bonus, in c there is a ternary operator, it works like this

   ```
   count += (c == myChar) ? 1 : 0;
   ```

   it is equivalent to

   ```
   if (c == myChar)
       count += 1;
   else
       count += 0;
   ```

   also, there is a compound assignment operator `+=`

   ```
   x += y;
   ```

   means

   ```
   x = x + y;
   ```

This is a repaired version of your program

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void fin(int jsCount);
int jsCounter();

int main()
{
    int jsCount = jsCounter();
    fin(jsCount);
}

int jsCounter()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int   c;
    int   count  = 0;
    char  myChar = 'l';

    fp = fopen("Doc.c", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening the file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        count += (c == myChar) ? 1 : 0;
    return count;
}

void
fin(int jsCount)
{
    printf("You have a total of %d", jsCount);
}
```

Comment: Ahh, yes, thank you. I have fixed this issue in my code -- still does not return the correct value however :(

Comment: @Christopher why did you change the question's code, now my answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have updated the code to ensure no one responds with the same answer. I have pointed you out having corrected me in my "edit" notes at the bottom

Comment: I have also ensured that fopen is not returning NULL

Comment: @Christopher I checked your code, and it has more issues, read the update.

Comment: +1 for all your help, I really appreciate it. I have made the changes to my source code and recompiled, but still the same results.

Comment: @Christopher The code works. I tested it, how are you testing it?

Comment: I have also added the ternary operator, and although I have no more errors or warnings I am still finding that I get 0 for my values. And yes, my code now looks exactly as you have posted here as the "repaired" version.

Comment: I am compiling and running with CodeBlocks, the file being read is located in the same file as my exe..  If you say it is working I will try to play around with my pathing, but if it was null it shouldnt return 0 when I am testing

Comment: How did you determine the correct value? and why do you say the program is giving wrong answer?

Comment: It says to me "You have a total of 0"

Comment: There was some weird problem with pathing -- yes code is working now! Thank you very much! Especially with teaching me the ternary operator! Very cool!